# ¿Por qué no se cambia el texto de los jTextField?

Tags: java, java-swing, jframe, jtextfield

En un proyecto de java swing, tengo que buscar un objeto depende del dato que ingrese y mostrar los otros datos de ese objeto en unos jTextFields, cuando debuggeo en NetBeans las variables cambian, por lo que esa función de buscar si sirve, pero los jTextFields no cambian. He intendado varias formas y ninguna funciona, los jTextFields siempre quedan con el valor que tienen en el design.

No incluyo los getter y setter para que no quede tan largo.

La clase donde tengo los métodos:

```
public class Manager {
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
static Search search = new Search();    
static Person Persons[] = new Person[3];
static int i = 0;

public static void searchPersonInfo(String idNumber) {
    for(int j = 0; j < Persons.length; j++){
        if(Persons[j] != null && idNumber.equals(Persons[j].getIdNumber())){
            search.fillTextFields(Persons[j]);
        }
      }
    }
```

La clase del swing:

```
public class Search extends javax.swing.JFrame {
public Search() {
    initComponents();
}
private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
   Manager manager = new Manager();
   manager.searchPersonInfo(jTextField1.getText());

}

public void fillTextFields(Person person){
    jTextField2.setText((person.getName()));
    jTextField3.setText((person.getLastName()));
    jTextField4.setText((person.getIdType()));
}
}
```

La clase del objeto:

```
public class Person{
private String name;
private String lastName;
private String idType;
private String idNumber;

public Person(String name, String lastName, String idType, String idNumber) {
  this.name = name;
  this.lastName = lastName;
  this.idType = idType;
  this.idNumber = idNumber;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El problema es que en tu clase Manager estas creando un nuevo objeto Search, que es sobre el cual intentas llenar los datos, en lugar de llenar los datos en el objeto search que ha llamado a la busqueda.
Existen muchas formas de arreglar este codigo, sin embargo yo propongo crear un setter para el objeto search, de esta manera puedes utilizar el mismo objeto Manager en multiples instancias de la clase search, tu codigo quedaria de la siguiente manera:

```
public class Manager {
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    static Search search;
    static Person Persons[] = new Person[3];
    static int i = 0;

    public static void setSearchFrame(Search searchWindow){
        search=searchWindow;
    }

    public static void searchPersonInfo(String idNumber) {
        for(int j = 0; j < Persons.length; j++){
            if(Persons[j] != null && idNumber.equals(Persons[j].getIdNumber())){
                if(search!=null){
                    search.fillTextFields(Persons[j]);       
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Una ves que la clase Manager, puede recibir el search donde llenar los JTextView, solo resta setearlo antes de llamar al metodo searchPersonInfo de la siguiente manera:

```
public class Search extends javax.swing.JFrame {
public Search() {
    initComponents();
}
private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
   Manager manager = new Manager();
   manager.setSearch(this);
   manager.searchPersonInfo(jTextField1.getText());

}

public void fillTextFields(Person person){
    jTextField2.setText((person.getName()));
    jTextField3.setText((person.getLastName()));
    jTextField4.setText((person.getIdType()));
}
}
```

Comment: Si funcionó, muchísimas gracias, te quiero mucho :'v